# Creating a xib file template

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, xib

I have created a xib file like the following:

[image: http://s16.postimg.org/n5ukz8j4l/Ekran_Resmi_2013_12_23_13_07_42.png]

I need to make this into a template as I don't want to have to recreate this multiple times. How can i go about doing this ?

Thank you in advance.

Regards..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Add a sub view class, named whatever you want, I'll call it MyTamp.
2 - Connect your xib to properties in that class.
3 - Whenever you need you tamplate in the code use:

```
NSArray* nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyTamp"
                                                  owner:self
                                                options:nil];

MyTamp* myView = [ nibViews objectAtIndex: 0];
```

4 - Use the properties you've set to update the view then added to whatever view you want.

Hope that helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to read this article: [Embedding custom-view Nibs in another Nib: Towards the holy grail](https://blog.compeople.eu/apps/?p=142)

They explain really good how to approach this issue.